# Azure - Log custom events in azure and load logs to show in Asp.net UI

Tags: c#, azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

I wish to leverage the **logging services/feature**s available in azure (Azure monitor/App insights/Log Analytics/etc ) and use them to store the custom events arising out of customers' actions in my app. Events like updating a record, adding, or deleting records, within my app, and also wish to leverage the search capabilities provided by the azure services, within my App via REST or SDK.

I wish to show those logs in grid form in my Asp.net UI and let the users visualize the logs and take actions after analyzing them. By providing the abstraction, I can give the user the ability to log anything that he likes while using my application and also have a search ability, but I will provide the interface to store and load the logs.

I am thinking that I can use the azure app insights for the same, but I don't see any SDK code or REST API to load the logs, provide the search capabilities to the user.

Is there a better path that I can take than going for Azure app insights?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/overview

Answer (score 1):

I zeroed into using the Log Analytics Workspace's "Custom logs" feature. This provides a REST endpoint to log the data and SDK to retrieve the data. Here is the link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api

Answer (score 0):

**Please check if given steps and references help to work around:**

> am thinking that I can use the azure app insights for the same, but I don't see any SDK code or REST API to load the logs, provide the search capabilities to the user.

- You can filter and track the telemetry data before it's sent from the SDK by implementing `ITelemetryProcessor`.
- To get your custom events data, you can use the code like `customEvents | summarize sum(itemCount)` in Logs Page which comes from the `trackEvent(...)`.
- Here is the **[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#custom-events-in-analytics)** given code in multiple programming languages to track the custom events and metrics in Analytics.

**To provide the custom events and metrics data to the end user, there is the [data access API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/overview) from the Azure Portal.**

**Other ways to extract data include [export from Analytics to Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-power-bi) and [continuous export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry).**

**References:**

1. [Azure Application Insights doesn't show custom events created in Azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848609/azure-application-insights-doesnt-show-custom-events-created-in-azure-function)
2. [Best Practices in Handling the Application Insights Custom Events](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/tracking-application-insights-custom-events)